# Why can't I share my internet access wireless to wireless on Ubuntu even thought I could do it on Windows 10 with the same card?

Tags: wireless, 20.04, internet, windows-10, hot-spot

I have tried sharing my WIFI connection via a hotspot in Windows 10, and it worked perfectly, with an added latency of 10ms, at the worst.

But on the same laptop, I can't share my internet connection in the same way, via the settings app, on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

What's the reason? Also, if there's a workaround, please enlighten me.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html.en

Comment: @PonJar No. It's a documentation on how to create a WIFI-hotspot.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify your question. You have tagged it with hot-spot. If you aren’t trying to create one to share it what are you trying to do, what have you tried and what aspect of sharing is not working.

Comment: I am indeed trying to create a WIFI hotspot, using my laptop's default WLAN interface.(internal wifi card)

I can do it in Windows 10 using the 'Settings' app. I can be connected to a WIFI network and have WIFI hotspot turned on at the same time. No visible latency issues (10ms at the worst)

The problem is, I'm unable to do the same using the provided options in the gnome-control-center(While connected to wifi). However, I can do it using [Create-AP](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap).

**What's keeping me from creating such a wifi-hotspot using the Ubuntu settings app?**

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you with that. If I were you I would ask your question again, describe how it works with Windows, and Create-AP, but not with the settings app. Don’t use the Windows tag or the internet tag, You question is about wireless hotspot on 20.04. There was not enough in the original question to answer it other than the way I did. With the extra clarity anyone who follows the relevant tags may take note and be able to help. Good luck!